# How to allow clicking on row elements in dynatree

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I want to render dynatree node with several checkboxes and select any, but when I click on checkbox, happens click on row, how can I disable click on row and enable clicking on elements, located in node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple. Use from server `noLink: true`(node title will be `span`, not `a`) and don't remove `e.preventDefault`, because

> Make sure that clicks stop, otherwise `<a href='#'>` jumps to the top